# FutureWarning: statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA and statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA have been deprecated

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

While using ARMA to fit a model:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARMA
```

I am getting a warning in my console:

```
C:\Users\lfc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py:472: FutureWarning: 
statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA and statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA have been deprecated in favor of statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA (note the . between arima and model) and statsmodels.tsa.SARIMAX. These will be removed after the 0.12 release.

statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA makes use of the statespace framework and
is both well tested and maintained.

To silence this warning and continue using ARMA and ARIMA until they are
removed, use:

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', 'statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA',
                        FutureWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', 'statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA',
                        FutureWarning)

warnings.warn(ARIMA_DEPRECATION_WARN, FutureWarning)
```

How do I discard the warning?

Comment: You can run the code that is in the warning exactly if you want to silence them. These have been removed from the future v0.13 release.  You should instead use statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA which is the future version.

Answer (score 12):

This warning is occuring due to deprication of the ARIMA package "statsmodels\tsa\arima_model".

Instead, import the statsmodel with:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

And fit ARIMA model as:

```
model = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(train_data, order=(1,1,2))
result = model.fit()
```

Answer (score 10):

As of today, the `statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA` and `statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA` have
been removed in favor of `statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA` (without `_`) and `statsmodels.tsa.SARIMAX`.

This is because `statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA` makes use of the `statespace` framework and they're both well tested and maintained.
It also offers alternative specialized parameter estimators.

If you try to use `ARMA` from `statsmodels.tsa.arima_model` you'll get `NotImplementedError` message error.

A quick fix to use `ARIMA` model could be like this:

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
model = ARIMA(dataFrame.columnName, order=(1,0,0))
```

You can find more details in this [issue](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3884).

Comment: sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA plot_predict is not defined.  what should I use

Comment: @GoldenLion for ARIMA model you can use `your_model.predict(start = start_date, end = end_date)` then `plot()` the predictions and use `plot_forecast(value)` for the forecast.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
```

Please change to following

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
```

Answer (score 2):

**Run the code below to ignore ARIMA warnings**

`import warnings`

`warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")`